# Pass c# structure array to c++

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, structure

I work on c++ dll and have any problem!
my header file is like this

```
struct ST_DevInfo
{
    EN_DevType de_type;        
    int screen_width;          
    int screen_height;         
    char dev_name[256];        
    char id[14];               
    char sboox_version[16];    
    char fpga_version[16];     
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int CB_GetDeviceList(ST_DevInfo* buff,int length);
```

and c++ code

```
int CB_GetDeviceList(ST_DevInfo* buff,int length)
{
    buff = (ST_DevInfo *)malloc(sizeof(ST_DevInfo) * length);

    return GetDeviceList(buff, length);
}
```

now i use this function in c# like this

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct ST_DevInfo
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
            public EN_DevType de_type;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
            public int screen_width;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
            public int screen_height;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1, SizeConst = 256)]
            public char[] dev_name;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1, SizeConst = 14)]
            public char[]  id;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1, SizeConst = 16)]
            public char[]  sboox_version;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1, SizeConst = 16)]
            public char[]  fpga_version;
        };

[DllImport(dllName, EntryPoint = "CB_GetDeviceList", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern
            int CB_GetDeviceList([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ref ST_DevInfo[] buff, 
                                    int length);
```

and finally i use this function in my program like this

```
ST_DevInfo[] buff = new ST_DevInfo[dev_length];
int ret = BBIA.CB_GetDeviceList( ref buff, dev_length);
```

but after retrieve from **CB_GetDeviceList** my buff variable assigned but not has any value(contain 0x00). i test it in c++ and it work fine!!
i think a have problem on this line

> buff = (ST_DevInfo *)malloc(sizeof(ST_DevInfo) * length);

Comment: Remove the `malloc` in your C++ code since you're already passing allocated memory to the function. You're actually writing your data to a new array, never modifying the one passed from C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your C# code you're doing this:

```
ST_DevInfo[] buff = new ST_DevInfo[dev_length];
int ret = BBIA.CB_GetDeviceList( ref buff, dev_length);
```

Which is allocating an array, and passing that (by a double pointer since you have `ref`), to the C++ code.

In your C++ code you are doing:

```
int CB_GetDeviceList(ST_DevInfo* buff,int length)
{
    buff = (ST_DevInfo *)malloc(sizeof(ST_DevInfo) * length);
    return GetDeviceList(buff, length);
}
```

Which is taking an array (and not as a double pointer) and changing that (local) pointer to point to some new memory. So your original array from C# will never be touched by the C++ code.

First, remove the `malloc` call completely. Then change your pinvoke to something like:

```
[DllImport( ... )]
public static extern int CB_GetDeviceList( [In, Out] ST_DevInfo[] buff, int length );
```

And call as before but without the `ref`. `In, Out` is needed to tell the marshaller that you expect the pinvoke call to modify the data. They are not necessary in every case, but in your case I'm not a 100% sure so I'd keep them just in case.